# Bind vuejs function as data with context vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use a function as a data property. This seems to work fine as in the case of the 'works' data property. However I need the this context in the function so that I can calculate values stored in the this.shoppingCart (another property).

Is this possible? If so what am I doing wrong?

```
 new Vue({
    el: '#vueApp',

    data: {

        shoppingCart: [],      

        works : function () {
            return "testfunc";
        },
        totalPriceCalcProperty : function () {

             this.totalPrice = this.shoppingCart.reduce(function(total, cartItem){

                console.log(total, cartItem);
                return total + parseFloat(cartItem.price);

            }, 0);
        }
    },

    methods: {

       totalPriceCalc: function () {

            this.totalPrice = this.shoppingCart.reduce(function(total, cartItem){

                console.log(total, cartItem);
                return total + parseFloat(cartItem.price);

            }, 0);
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this by using `methods`, not `data`.
`data` is helping you to store something rather than handle some actions.

In methods, you can call this.xxx to get the properties from `data` or `property`